# python network test application

Tags: python, networking, automation

I am working to a python application for some operational test on a Arista brand Network (more info here: https://gitlab.com/networkAutomation/pyateos)

I am the only one doing coding in my team so I do not have much chance to compare myself with someone really knowledgeable that can suggest me a better way to do coding. So far I compare my code with pylint (great way to learn) as well as blogs and community. Would be great if you can have a look and tell me what you think. I am available to any sort of suggestion. Thanks for your time.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import re
import sys
import time
import json
import argparse
from jsondiff import diff
from pyeapi import load_config
from pyeapi import connect_to
from plugins.acl import acl
from plugins.as_path import as_path
from plugins.bgp_evpn import bgp_evpn
from plugins.bgp_ipv4 import bgp_ipv4
from plugins.interface import interface
from plugins.ip_route import ip_route
from plugins.mlag import mlag
from plugins.ntp import ntp
from plugins.prefix_list import prefix_list
from plugins.route_map import route_map
from plugins.snmp import snmp
from plugins.stp import stp
from plugins.vlan import vlan
from plugins.vrf import vrf
from plugins.vxlan import vxlan

def arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog='pyATEOS',
        description='''pyATEOS - A simple python application for operational status test on
        Arista device. Based on pyATS idea and pyeapi library for API calls.'''
        )
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument(
        '-B',
        '--before',
        dest='before',
        action='store_true',
        help='''write json file containing the test result BEFORE.
        To be run BEFORE the config change. 
        File path example: $PWD/before/ntp/router1_ntp.json'''
        )
    group.add_argument(
        '-A',
        '--after',
        dest='after',
        action='store_true',
        help='''write json file containing the test result AFTER.
        To be run AFTER the config change.
        File path example: $PWD/after/ip_route/router1_ip_route.json'''
        )
    group.add_argument(
        '-C',
        '--compare',
        dest='compare',
        action='store_true',
        help='''diff between before and after test files.
        File path example: $PWD/diff/snmp/router1_snmp.json'''
        )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-i',
        '--inventory',
        dest='inventory',
        help='specify pyeapi inventory file path'
        )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-n',
        '--node',
        dest='node',
        help='specify inventory node. Multiple values are accepted separated by space',
        nargs='+',
        required=True
        )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-t',
        '--test',
        dest='test',
        help='run one or more specific test. Multiple values are accepted separated by space',
        nargs='+',
        required=True
        )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-F',
        '--file_name',
        dest='file',
        help='''provide the 2 filename IDs to compare, separated by space.
        BEFORE first, AFTER second. i.e [..] -C -f 1582386835 1582387929''',
        nargs='+',
        type=int,
        )

    if parser.parse_args().compare and parser.parse_args().file is None:
        parser.error("-C/--compare requires -F/--file_name.")

    return parser.parse_args()


def flags(args):
    returned_dict = dict()

    if args.inventory:
        inventory = args.inventory
    else:
        inventory = 'eos_inventory.ini'

    if args.compare:
        if args.file:
            assert len(args.file) == 2 and (args.file[0] - args.file[1]) < 0, '''
            provide the 2 filename IDs to compare, separated by space. 
            BEFORE first, AFTER second. i.e [..] -C -f 1582386835 1582387929'''
            file_name = args.file
    else:
        file_name = None

    returned_dict.update(
        inventory=inventory,
        node=args.node,
        test=args.test,
        before=args.before,
        after=args.after,
        compare=args.compare,
        file_name=file_name
        )

    return returned_dict


class WriteFile():
    def __init__(self, test, node, file_name=None):

        self.test = test
        self.node = node
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.pwd_before = os.getcwd() + '/before/{}'.format(self.test)
        self.pwd_after = os.getcwd() + '/after/{}'.format(self.test)
        self.pwd_diff = os.getcwd() + '/diff/{}'.format(self.test)
        self.time_file = round(time.time())

    def write_before(self, result):
        if not os.path.exists(self.pwd_before):
            os.makedirs(self.pwd_before)

        with open('{0}/{1}_{2}_{3}.json'.format(
                self.pwd_before,
                self.time_file,
                self.test,
                self.node
            ), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            json.dump(result, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
            print('BEFORE file ID for {} test: {}'.format(self.test.upper(), self.time_file))


    def write_after(self, result):
        if not os.path.exists(self.pwd_after):
            os.makedirs(self.pwd_after)

        with open('{0}/{1}_{2}_{3}.json'.format(
                self.pwd_after,
                self.time_file,
                self.test,
                self.node
            ), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            json.dump(result, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
            print('AFTER file ID for {} test: {}'.format(self.test.upper(), self.time_file))


    def write_diff(self):

        if not os.path.exists(self.pwd_diff):
            os.makedirs(self.pwd_diff)

        def replace(string, substitutions):

            substrings = sorted(substitutions, key=len, reverse=True)
            regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, substrings)))
            sub_applied = regex.sub(lambda match: substitutions[match.group(0)], string)

            for integer in re.findall(r'\d+:', sub_applied):
                sub_applied = sub_applied.replace(integer, f'"{integer[:-1]}":')

            return sub_applied

        substitutions = {
            '\'':'\"',
            'insert':'"insert"',
            'delete':'"delete"',
            'True':'true',
            'False':'false',
            '(':'[',
            ')':']',
            }

        try:
            before = open('{0}/{1}_{2}_{3}.json'.format(
                self.pwd_before,
                self.file_name[0],
                self.test,
                self.node), 'r')
        except FileNotFoundError as error:
            print(error)
            sys.exit(1)

        try:
            after = open('{0}/{1}_{2}_{3}.json'.format(
                self.pwd_after,
                self.file_name[1],  
                self.test,
                self.node), 'r')
        except FileNotFoundError as error:
            print(error)
            sys.exit(1)

        json_diff = str(diff(before, after, load=True, syntax='symmetric'))
        edit_json_diff = replace(json_diff, substitutions)
        diff_file_id = str((self.file_name[0] - self.file_name[1]) * -1)

        with open('{0}/{1}_{2}_{3}.json'.format(
                self.pwd_diff,
                diff_file_id,
                self.test,
                self.node), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            json.dump(json.loads(edit_json_diff), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
            print('DIFF file ID for {} test: {}'.format(self.test.upper(), diff_file_id))


def bef_aft_com(**kwargs):

    test_run = list()

    if kwargs:
        before = kwargs.get('before')
        after = kwargs.get('after')
        compare = kwargs.get('compare')
        file_name = kwargs.get('file_name')
        nodes = kwargs.get('node')
        test = kwargs.get('test')


    test_all = [
        'acl',
        'as_path',
        'bgp_evpn',
        'bgp_ipv4',
        'interface',
        'ip_route',
        'mlag',
        'ntp',
        'prefix_list',
        'route_map',
        'snmp',
        'stp',
        'vlan',
        'vrf',
        'vxlan'
    ]


    if 'mgmt' in test:
        test.remove('mgmt')
        test_run.extend(('ntp', 'snmp'))
    elif 'routing' in test:
        test.remove('routing')
        test_run.extend(('bgp_evpn', 'bgp_ipv4', 'ip_route'))
    elif 'layer2' in test:
        test.remove('layer2')
        test_run.extend(('stp', 'vlan', 'vxlan'))
    elif 'ctrl' in test:
        test.remove('ctrl')
        test_run.extend(('acl', 'as_path', 'prefix_list', 'route_map'))
    elif 'all' in test:
        test.remove('all')
        test_run = test_all

    test_run.extend(test)

    for node in nodes:
        for test in list(set(test_run)):
            if test not in test_all:
                raise ValueError('Test name not valid. Please check the test list available under plugins folder')
            else:
                if before:
                    wr_before = WriteFile(test, node)
                    wr_before.write_before(eval(test)(connect_to(node)).show)
                elif after:
                    wr_after = WriteFile(test, node)
                    wr_after.write_after(eval(test)(connect_to(node)).show)
                elif compare:
                    wr_diff = WriteFile(test, node, file_name)
                    wr_diff.write_diff()


def main():

    my_flags = flags(arguments())

    load_config(my_flags.get('inventory'))

    if my_flags.get('test'):
        bef_aft_com(**my_flags)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```